# Sort class by field and by size of value

Tags: java, class, sorting

Good morning. I have class, which contain data in this format: [int][Object]. I never worked with classes, i usually use Lists, Maps, now i don't understand how to implement this in common classes. How to sort by field in classes?
 Be careful , my toString only showing field code without field number.

```
     I would like to sort this class by size of value[Object]
( "1 1234", "2 35881", ... "7 22" --> "7 22", "1 1234", "2 35881")



        public class Record {
            private int number;
            private Object code;

         ... Getters/Setters 

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return (String)(this.code);
        }

        }


        public class Storage
        {
            List<Record> record;
            public Storage(){

                this.record = new ArrayList<Record>();

            }

            public void addRecord(Record record) {
                this.record.add(record);
            }
            public Record getRecord(int number){
                return this.record.get(number);
            }
            public void delRecord(int number){
                this.record.remove(number);
            }

            public Integer sizeStorage(){
                return record.size();
            }

        }

    public class Start {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Start reading from Xls");
    ReaderXls read = new ReaderXls();

    Storage storageRZS =  readrzs.ReadXls("Text1obj",2,12);

    .....
            System.out.println(storageRZS.getRecord(5));
            System.out.println(storageRZS.getRecord(7));
            System.out.println(storageRZS.getRecord(10));

    2122
    189266
    244

The result should be this:
        244
        2122
        189266
```

Comment: You'll need to make a custom `Comparator`

Comment: What do you mean by "sort by field"? Please explain how your sorting works; the "size" of an `Object` (and nothing more specific) doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wissh to access records in an ordered way you will need to use a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or implement [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your Record class.

Sample:

```
 Collections.sort(listOfRecords, new Comparator<Record>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
                //null checks

                /*Compare the object field according to your custom logic. 
                 Here it is assumed that getObjectCodeAsInt() will return an integer equivalent of the objectCode.*/
                if(o1.getObjectCodeAsInt() > o2.getObjectCodeAsInt())
                    return 1;
                else if(o1.getObjectCodeAsInt() < o2.getObjectCodeAsInt())
                    return -1;

                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the code provided; he's wanting to sort on a field of type `Object`, not the `int`.

Comment: Of course, its not a complete runnable code, hence `getObjectCodeAsInt()`. The point was giving the idea. Anyways, edited a comment to make it more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a customer `Comparator` for the same. Read [how to sort user defined objects](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/)

Answer (score 1):

I am little unsure about the exactness of the question.
However if you wish to sort the collection such as list by different class attributes (fields as you say), you may look into [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

You will need to implement the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface for each of sorting attribute.

Regards
VJ